# Custom AVPlayerVIew: do you know which initializer is used by default?

Tags: avplayerview

The standard NSView initializer initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame; is not getting called in my custom view. I've tried simple init, but so far, nothing is called.  Also, the drawRect: method is not called. So how is one to intercept the initialization of the AVPlayerView?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this (using Objective-C) - it is:

- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;